# How to get the type of transaction (Send/Receive/Approve/Swap) and the ERC20 tokens involved in that transaction?

Tags: transactions, ether, wallets, hash

I', getting to know the Ethereum technology (so rookie level). By far, with the free APIs (etherscan.io, ethplorer.io, coingecko) I have been able to build a "watch wallet". It looks like this:
[image: My App]

But I can't seem to find the API which gives me more detail about all the Transactions in the given wallet. API does give me the hash, block, gas, status, address (from/to), etc... But I don't know the tokens (assets) that were involved in those transactions and I don't know which action took place (Sent/ Received/Swapped/Approved ...)

Here's the raw info I get from the api (image 2), can someone guide me to the next step of how to extract those detail data?

[image: Image 2]

P/s: What I'm trying to achieve looks like this (Image 3: Zerion app)
[image]

Comment: P/s 2: I'm using this api to get the transactions: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you are not querying the right endpoint. If you want to fetch ERC-20 events, you must do the following query :

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&startblock=0&endblock=99999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

Notice that unfortunately, the `input` field value is `deprecated`. This is what you should have used to determine the event (`Trade`, `Approval`, `Send` ...)

Fortunately, we can call another method to get this data. Let's get the input data for the last transaction, so transaction with hash `0xdceb6a76cc83802ddabf8efc0b0458dfa9150866df3ad826686e47b303259cd8`

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getTransactionByHash&txhash=0xdceb6a76cc83802ddabf8efc0b0458dfa9150866df3ad826686e47b303259cd8&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

You can then get the encoded input data : `0xa9059cbb000000000000000000000000ddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005af3107a4000`

To decode it, you can use [abi-decoder](https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder). You must provide to abi-decoder the abi of ERC-20 contract :

```
const erc20abistr = '[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"balance","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]'
```

Then do something like this :

```js
import abiDecoder from "abi-decoder"
const erc20Abi = JSON.parse(erc20abistr);
let decodedData = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(input);
console.log(input);
```

Note : instead of getting your hands dirty with etherscan api, you should try using [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/) instead

Comment: That was a very clear explanation. Thank you! I guess to learn more about Ethereum since I have little what to do with the given data

Comment: Hi Xavier, 
Thanks for the detailed explanation.
How would you use web3js to do this? I don't see an option to get transactions...

Comment: @RoyToledo There is one. You can use getTransaction https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction and then get the input from there.